# MFC C++ on screen keyboard as parent dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to extend the functionality of a third party application which uses keyboard shortcuts for use on a touch screen monitor.
My plan to achieve this was to make an on screen keyboard to feed keystrokes (virtual) to the application and to change the window style to embed it into the keyboard.

As the application [(Mach3)](http://www.machsupport.com/software/mach3/) supports extending the functionality with plugins this is how I wanted to achieve my goal.

For the embedding I modified the code from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18724/Hosting-exe-applications-into-a-dialog) so that on loading mach3, the application dialog is immediately embedded into my dialog.

For the keyboard functionality I used code from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32563/Virtual-On-Screen-Keyboard-Example) to give the window the `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` style and handle being moved correctly.

The problem that I have is that when I give focus to another window (for instance notepad) and press a button to generate a keypress, the keypress is received correctly by the other application, however when I give the focus to the embedded window and press a button, the focus is shifted to the button and no keypress is received by the child dialog.

How do I prevent the focus from being changed like this?
Is this a simple thing I'm missing or do I need to drastically change my approach?

I would post some code, but there is rather a lot of it and I'm not sure which bits would be the most relevant to solving this problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372202/let-my-mfc-dialog-receive-keystroke-events-before-its-controls-mfc-win32-equiva

Comment: that seems to be different, i don't want my dialog to swallow the keypressed, i want them to be passed to the application window and for the focus not to be changed when doing so, i think the focus is the big issue here.

Comment: I think your issue is that since the embedded application is inside your dialog which also contains the virtual keyboard, the code that transfers focus back to the previous window (in OnMouseMove) probably just transfers focus to your own dialog and to the virtual keyboard button. I feel that this needs some testing to make sure. By the way, I see in the comments section of the MFC article, that there is a correction for the project, have you tried it?

Comment: I had missed that, thank you, i don't have access to VS2013 (what i'm using to compile it) while i'm at work, so i'll try this when i get home.

Comment: I've made the changes shown in the comments and the no activate part works much better (window seems unable to keep focus at all but can still be moved) however I still can't keep the focus on the embedded dialog when I press a button. in fact as soon as I move the mouse out of the area of the embedded dialog the control that had focus (the MDI line) loses focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the cause of my problem, which now allows me to create an embedded dialog with the parent dialog acting as an on screen keyboard.

firstly as commented above I needed to make some changes to my keyboard code, specifically the overridden `OnNcLButtonDown` which the article says should be:

```
void COnScreenKeyboardDlg::OnNcLButtonDown(UINT nHitTest, CPoint point)
{
 if (!m_hForegroundWnd)
 {
  // store current foreground window
  m_hForegroundWnd = ::GetForegroundWindow();
  // temporarily make this dialog an activatable window
  ModifyStyleEx(WS_EX_NOACTIVATE,0);
  // make this dialog foreground
  SetForegroundWindow();
 }
 CDialog::OnNcLButtonDown(nHitTest, point);
}
```

but should actually be:

```
void CWrapperDialog::OnNcLButtonDown(UINT nHitTest, CPoint point) {
    SetForegroundWindow();
    CDialog::OnNcLButtonDown(nHitTest, point);
}
```

secondly the article says to override `OnMouseMove` with:

```
void COnScreenKeyboardDlg::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
 if (m_hForegroundWnd)
 {
  // make the previous foreground window active
  ::SetForegroundWindow(m_hForegroundWnd);
  // make this dialog non-activating
  ModifyStyleEx(0,WS_EX_NOACTIVATE);
  // set it to NULL to mark that we do not need to do this again
  m_hForegroundWnd = NULL;
 }
 CDialog::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```

the comment below "corrects" this to:

```
void CWrapperDialog::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) {
    ::SetActiveWindow(0);
    CDialog::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```

however I found that with this code I would get flashing from the focus changing whenever I moved the mouse, so I omitted it entirely.

Lastly the keyboard example used `DoModal` to create the dialog, whereas I was using `Create`

I created a wrapper function I could call with `AfxBeginThread`:

```
UINT CWrapperDialog::ThreadDoModal(LPVOID pParam){
    CWrapperDialog* dlg;
    dlg = ((CWrapperDialog*)pParam);
    dlg->DoModal();
    return 0;
}
```

and called it:

```
dlg = new CWrapperDialog;
AfxBeginThread(dlg->ThreadDoModal, dlg);
```

and now the messages are being passed correctly.

Thanks to o_weisman for the tip regarding the changes to the example as this made a massive difference.